# Can you monitor and alter register values in renode the way it is done in IAR systems?

Tags: embedded, iar, bare-metal, renode

I recently came across [Renode](https://renode.io/#downloads), which claims to simulate exact binaries and of an embedded software. Now, can I use a software like renode to debug my baremetal embedded software ? (monitor and edit register values the way it is done in IAR embedded workbench) ? How exactly do these two differ ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very generic question, but the answer is "yes, you can".

When you load your platform you can use the Monitor to access the `cpu` object, and from it - some registers, e.g. `cpu PC`.

If you just run the `cpu` command you will get a list of all available properties, registers among them.

It's very difficult to answer the question on differences with IAR workbench. Renode is open source, it supports multi-node, deterministic emulation of heterogeneous systems. But you'd need to be a bit more specific to have a precise answer here.

Disclaimer: I'm one of Renode developers